# bootstrap3 nested row incorrect behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am misunderstanding something about the nested rows with Bootstrap...

- let's say I have a container of 1200px.
- then I have a first div with col-lg-4 which means 400px for the first level.
- inside this col-lg-4 I create a second level row, my understanding is that the new row will act as container.

The new row width should be used to compute the column breakdown, here 400px would mean "col-xs", did I get that wrong ?

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYngJ.png)

```
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid">
  <div class="row">
  Let's say the container is 1200px
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="row" style="border:1px solid blue;">
              This div size should be 1200/4=300px (which means <b>col-xs</b> only should be active)            
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
              <div style="border:1px solid red;">
                But it is always using col-lg-3, instead of col-sm-6
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  How can I have the red box to use the <b>xs/sm</b> size and use half of the 300px ?
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

[Code Example available here](http://www.bootply.com/zQkdMfTM64)

**From the given example, how could I have the red node to use col-sm-6 instead of col-lg-3?**

I need to make him think that it's on small screen instead of large...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of a nested column is relative to it's parent, but isn't dependent on the screen breakpoints like `col-xs`. The l,m,sm,xs breakpoints only relate to the entire screen/viewport with, not the parent container. Maybe it will be clearer if you think about it in percentage instead of pixels.

`col-*-4` is 33% width of the container

`col-*-6` is 50% width of the container

So while you're calculation of 400px is about right on 1200px viewport, it's not going to change the breakpoint (xs) of the nested/child column(s). Use `col-lg-6` on the nested column if you want it to be 50% width of it's parent on large screens. If want it to be 50% of the parent on all screens use `col-xs-6` on the nested column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, try to understand it

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="border:1px solid">
  <div>
  Let's say the container is 1200px
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid blue;">
      <div>
              This div size should be 1200/4=300px           
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="border:1px solid red;">
          This use col-sm-6
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  How can I have the red box to use the <b>xs/sm</b> size and use half of the 300px ?
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Basically, you dont need to use lg on everything, just use sm and understand it first.
http://www.bootply.com/eMimw5tMGd